# Transferring Z values from point layer to line layer using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-join

I have two shapefiles, point and polyline, and I am trying to transfer Z values from point layer to polyline layer to calculate the pipe slope (by using manhole's depth and z value).  In the attachment you can see the attribute table of each layer.

What procedure should I use?

[image]

Comment: I assume you are just wanting to join z values in the manhole layer to the polyline, not actually update the z value of the polyline vertex?

Comment: Yes I want to join z values to Up-stream and Down-stream of pipe layer(start and end of pipe)